# Which MOSFET should I use for high-voltage inverter circuit

Tags: voltage, mosfet, current, fet

[image]

I have an inverter circuit with 2 MOSFETs alternating, a capacitor, and a couple of resistors.

When I supply 5 V I can see a high-frequency square wave, given the capacitor and resistors values.

When I raise the voltage to 12V and then to 24 V the output drops to zero.

I am using an IRF630 MOSFET.
I swapped out for an IRLZ44N and this time everything works fine, even at 24 V.

I don't understand this, since the IRF630 is rated at 200 V and the IRLZ44N at only 55 V. I am trying to read the specs and figure out what it is.

I want to eventually use this for a 150~200 V application and I'm not sure which MOSFET to get.

Is it something with the current that is keeping the IRF630 from turning on, or what? Don't MOSFETs work on voltage?

I have swapped out the capacitor and resistors to get varying results. I am using bigger resistor values to reduce current. Could this be the issue? I am looking for a MOSFET that can take 200-300 V with low current.

Comment: "Output dissapeared" is not clear. What does it mean?

Comment: Also, beside voltage ratings, timings are something to consider when you need high frequency switching using mosfets.

Comment: i edited. the output is zero volts. There is nothing when I play with the input voltage dial on my power supply.

Comment: I am looking at the data sheets. Where does it say MOSFET timing?

Comment: reading now. irlz44n says "fast switching" vs IRF630 says "for switching applications"

Comment: When you say `voltage inverter`, what do you actually mean? Are you aware that you will get very little power from this circuit as it currently stands? Are you also unaware that if you want a powerful output, you should design an oscillator that feeds the MOSFET rather than try and get all functionality into one or two transistors. The above circuit stops oscillating because it finds a linear point all too easily that has sufficient voltage on M3's drain to keep M2 on permanently. In other words, it's not a good design; Use a logic gate wired as an oscillator then, interface to a MOSFET.

Comment: yea I changed the resistor and capacitor values a few times around. I have a very low current in the circuit. could this be the issue? I like to reduce current if possible.

Comment: Are you trying to make an oscillator ? This 2-transistor circuit won't make a stable (predictable) oscillator.

Comment: I am getting ocsillation with the IRLZ44N . Not sure what resistors I used. I think the capacitor was 100pF or 1nF. the resistor values are high. higher than in picture i think

Comment: I want low current

Comment: 1. How are you protecting the FET gates from excessive voltage? 2. Please specify what you are actually wanting to do. At present this is very unclear.

Comment: what I want to do: make a ~200v source voltage into a high frequency pulse, to then control the PWM to lower the voltage. 
Please do not tell me to simply buy a SMPS, since I am trying to build this myself with simple components.

Comment: You want low current (i.e. signal) yet build your own SMPS? Which is it? Please clarify your actual load current using numbers, not words and intended usage.

Comment: You did not answer my crucial question. FETs have a max Vgs rating naed Vgsmax. Exceed this and the FETs will die. Typically  this is about 20V but it varies. Your circuit does not clamp the FET gates to within a safe voltage range.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit is fundamentally flawed, sadly: It will quickly destroy your FETs since the gate voltage is not limited. If you drive the circuit with more than 20V, you risk gate breakdown. Once this occurs, your expensive FETs are just paperweights. In fact, this is what might've already happened to your IRF630s. Apart from that, it's also just not a great oscillator as Andy aka already mentioned in the comments.

The circuit also consumes quite a lot more current than necessary. If you want a really low current high voltage oscillator, you could use a CMOS 555 timer chip, i.e. the ICM7555. This chip can oscillate with just a few hundred microamperes and it can also drive the gate of a MOSFET directly. Of course you'll have to generate a supply voltage for it. To do this, a simple resistor + zener shunt regulator should suffice (with a 15V zener, for example). Alternatively, you could use a high-voltage JFET or an appropriate linear regulator to generate 15V for the timer chip.

Comment: the problem is I have a supply of 170V and I am trying to build an ocsillation circuit with low power. I cannot use CMOS 555. Just FETs, capacitors, resistors, coils. No chips.

Comment: Why can't you use a chip? It's inexpensive and easy to use. Of course, you can also build a discrete oscillator and power that with 15V generated by a zener regulator. Building a discrete low power schmitt trigger might be your best bet.

Comment: I just want to build a 200V operated low power oscillator with basic components. No chips nothing complex. wouldnt the 200v to 15v zener regulation  heat up a lot?

Comment: can i message you on email or facebook to discuss my project. it is just a 200v to 20v circuit with a 300watt power to power a motor. I need it to be simple components and small enough to fit in 5"by5"by4"box

Comment: So you actually want to build a regulated switchmode power supply. That's quite difficult and you won't be able to make it any smaller or simpler (or cheaper) than an off-the-shelf power supply, especially not if you don't want to use ICs. That'll quickly become a many-hundred-component nightmare. TDK Corp has a power supply that does what you need: The HWS300-24. You can just buy it.